# How to write a stored procedure in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

The stored procedure which is there below need to be added in this code where I have written query.

```
if (ddlFormat.SelectedIndex != 0)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    con1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet dsDisp = new DataSet();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "Select DISTINCT Disposition from CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr where CallType=@CallType and SUBFormat=@Format";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallType", ddlCalltype.SelectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Format", ddlFormat.SelectedItem.Text);
    cmd.Connection = con1;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dsDisp);

    ddlDisp.DataTextField = "Disposition";
    ddlDisp.DataValueField = "Disposition";

    ddlDisp.DataSource = dsDisp.Tables[0];
    ddlDisp.DataBind();

    ddlDisp.Items.Insert(0, "<----Select---->");
    ddlDisp.Focus();
}

protected void ddlDisp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlDisp.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        DataSet dsSubDisp = new DataSet();

        using (cmd = new SqlCommand("Select distinct CallType,Disposition,SubDisposition,Format from  Loy_DispMstr where CallType=@CallType and SUBFormat=@Format and Disposition = @disposition", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallType",ddlCalltype.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Format", ddlFormat.SelectedValue);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disposition", ddlDisp.SelectedValue);
            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dsSubDisp);
        {
            ddlSubdisp.DataTextField = "SubDisposition";
            ddlSubdisp.DataValueField = "SubDisposition";
            ddlSubdisp.DataSource = dsSubDisp.Tables[0];
            ddlSubdisp.DataBind();

            ddlSubdisp.Items.Insert(0, "<----Select---->");
            ddlSubdisp.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlSubdisp.Focus();

            ddlDisp.Items.Insert(1, "ADD NEW VALUE");
            ddlDisp.SelectedIndex = 1;
            ddlDisp.Focus();
        }
    }

    if (ddlDisp.SelectedItem.Text == "ADD NEW VALUE" )
    {
        TextBox1.Visible = true;
        TextBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}

protected void ddlSubdisp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CallcenterConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    DataSet dsOut = new DataSet();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select PID,Memberstatus,calltype,format,disposition,subdisposition, man_data,creation_date,createdby,updation_date,updatedby from Loy_SubPlaceholder");
    cmd.Connection = con; 
    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
    sda.Fill(dsOut);
    ddlDisp.DataSource = dsOut.Tables[0];
    ddlDisp.DataValueField = "subdisposition";
    ddlDisp.DataTextField = "subdisposition";
    ddlDisp.DataBind();
    con.Open();

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
if @flag = '1'
begin
Select Formatid,Formatdetail,dispformat  From loy_Formatdetail with (nolock)
Where isactive='1' and memberstatus = 'Member' order by FormatDetail
end

if @flag = '2'
begin
Select DISTINCT Disposition from CallCenter..Loy_DispMstr 
where CallType=@CallType and SUBFormat=@Format
end

if @flag = '3'  
begin  
Select distinct CallType,Disposition,SubDisposition,Format from  Loy_DispMstr
where CallType=@CallType and SUBFormat=@Format and Disposition = @disposition
end
```

Comment: in the place of query i want to add store procedure

Answer (score 0):

In First code paragraph:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.CommandText = "sp_whatevername";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallType", ddlCalltype.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Format", ddlFormat.SelectedItem.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", "1");
```

In ddlDisp_SelectedIndexChanged:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_whatevername", con)) {
      cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CallType",ddlCalltype.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Format", ddlFormat.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@disposition", ddlDisp.SelectedValue);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", "1");

      con.Open();
      cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

I have updated code with Parameter as flag. Now you SP should have this parameters and from your specific condition you need to pass specific flag. In that way you can get result from the flag specific query.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks..but how will i use flag...in my store procedure i have added flag to every query...so pls can you tell how will i attach in this code

Comment: @ash : Pass it as a parameter